Use of さる in 侵攻さる
I came across this construct and I was wondering if the さる in 侵攻さる is some form of auxiliary or suru verb conjugation I don't know about. I couldn't really find a logical explanation for this use here. Fyi this is from the title of a song so basically the question is if this is a valid grammatical construct or just the use of artistic freedom.
Thanks in advance

In classical Japanese, the passive form of the "do" verb する was さる in the terminal / predicative / clause-ending form.  This basically had the so-called 下二段活用【しもにだんかつよう】 or "lower bigrade conjugation".  These all regularly shifted to the modern verb-stem pattern ending in -e, much like 食べる【たべる】 or 寝る【ねる】 or 焦げる【こげる】.  So classical さる becomes modern される.
The conjugation table for this verb:



Form
Classical:下二段【しもにだん】lower bigrade
Modern:下一段【しもいちだん】lower monograde




未然形【みぜんけい】Irrealis / incomplete
され-
され-


連用形【れんようけい】Continuative / -masu stem
され-
され-


終止形【しゅうしけい】Terminative / predicative
さる
される


連体形【れんたいけい】Attributive
さるる
される


已然形【いぜんけい】Realis (classical)仮定形【かていけい】Hypothetical (modern)
さるれ-
されれ-


命令形【めいれいけい】Imperative / Command
されよ
されろ・されよ



